# How to move to Next Tab upon selection of an Item in TListView in Firemonkey Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings, tlistview

I have TabControl with 2 TabItems for my mobile device development. The TabItem1 has a TListView for list of items populated using LiveBindings.

Here, the TabItem2 should provide the details of the selected item in TabItem1 — no issues here.

My question is — How to trigger the move from TabItem1 to TabItem2, during item selection, using a set of code in the TabItem1.OnItemClick event?

Comment: What's wrong with TabControl1.TabIndex:=1 ?

Comment: @DougRudd Perfect! Exactly what I want! Thank you.

Comment: Can you move your comment to the answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 1):

During item selection you should use the `TlistView` `OnItemClick` event => `ListView1ItemClick`, **not** the `TabItem1.OnItemClick` event.

Here's an example:

```pascal
procedure TForm.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  TabControl1.SetActiveTabWithTransition(TabItem2, TTabTransition.Slide);
end;
```